# Does struts2.3.15.3 security issue also affect the tiles plugin?

Tags: security, struts2, tiles2

I upgraded struts2 to 2.3.32 with no problem, but I also depend on struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar which I can't upgrade as easily. Is this a problem or is upgrading struts2-core enough to fix the issue?

Comment: Why can't you update tiles plugin also?

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/apache/struts-extras to *fix* security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I think. At [S2-046](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-046.html)'s workaround section I read:

> Another option is to remove the File Upload Interceptor from the stack

Which means that vulnerability was inside core. However, `struts2-tiles-plugin` does not have dependency to core!